# Semiconductor Physics: n-type Vs p-type region Energy level

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

My textbook claims that the energy level on the n-type region, with pentavalent impurities is much lower than the p-type, with trivalent impurities. My doubt is, does the energy level **of energy bands** depend on how many electrons overall are found on each atom (the size of the orbit) or the amount of force exerted on the electrons?

Comment: When you say energy level do you mean Fermi level? Or do you mean the level of the trap state associated with the impurity?

Comment: By energy level, I mean the energy level of the valence and conduction band of the n-type region prior to diffusion.

Comment: A band isn't a single level. It's a *band* of levels. Do you mean the band edges?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the energy level of a band depends on the electron configuration in the system because the levels and thus the bands are a collection of energy state that are or theoretically can be occupied by an electron.

An electron in a neutral atom occupies a specific energy state defined by its orbital. If you now merge more of this type of atom together to form a material of some sort, then you suddenly have several electrons occupying the same energy states overlapping.

But Pauli's exclusion principle forbids two electrons of the same system to occupy the same energy state. A rough picture of what happens is to image that one energy state squeezes itself slightly below the other, and the other slightly above. With many, many atoms of the same type merged, many such energy states will "stack up" tightly underneath and above each other. This "stack" of densely packed energy states from individual electrons constitutes what we call **an energy band**.

Since the energy bands are shaped by the energy states, and since the energy states are strictly defined from the electron orbit (its orbital numbers), then naturally, the energy bands depend on the electrons, both their number and configuration of each individual atom. With impurities you will see small or drastic changes to the configuration, but the final energy band will nevertheless depend on this configuration.

Comment: The exclusion principle allows exactly two electrons (of opposite spin) to occupy the 'same energy state'

Comment: @Whit3rd I would argue that different spins imply different energy states

Comment: Oh, two quantum states certainly, but uness there's a magnetic field (Zeeman effect) not distinct energy states.

Comment: @Whit3rd Ahh, I see. Good point, thank you.